# No column name showing up in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 but column name does not appear. I need to put in an empty string as the rows are populated manually in the report.

```
(SELECT '' As 'Total No of people')
```

It seems to show up as `(No column name)`

Comment: I just ran your posted TSQL and it worked as expected.

Comment: can you show your whole query.. workiing for me though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have

```
SELECT ID as 'ID',
(SELECT <....> FROM table WHERE <...> ) AS 'Total No of people'
FROM somewhere
```

You have to put the column name after the `)` for the inner select

Answer (score 3):

I will say it works correctly! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18149

But perhaps your problem is that you do (technically using a subquery)

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT '' As 'Total No of people') FROM SomeWhere
```

and that is wrong...

```
SELECT ID, '' As 'Total No of people' FROM SomeWhere
```

or

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT '') As 'Total No of people' FROM SomeWhere
```

but there is no reason for the inner `SELECT`

Comment: +1 For your First Answer which shows working. +1 for for cases where it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you put in tight order : SELECT '' As 'Total No of people' from PEOPLE

Comment: I think this should be in comment